# Multiple Activity In A CardView Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

What is the proper way to implement switch statement while navigating through a list of activity?

For example in my fragment, there are 3 cardviews where each is leading to different activity.

Unfortunately I'm still new to this and even I have googled multiple sites yet none could not provide me the result I wanted. This is what I currently got on my own progress.

Hopefully some of you could guide me further on this or provide link that may help.

```
package info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Selection;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import info.androidhive.materialdesign.R;

import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity;

/**
 * Created by venkataprasad.kukka on 02-01-2015.
 */
public class CardViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static ArrayList<FeddProperties> dataSet;

    public CardViewDataAdapter(ArrayList<FeddProperties> os_versions) {

        dataSet = os_versions;
    }


    @Override
    public CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
// create a new view
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.card_view, null);

        // create ViewHolder

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        FeddProperties fp = dataSet.get(i);

        viewHolder.tvVersionName.setText(fp.getTitle());
        viewHolder.iconView.setImageResource(fp.getThumbnail());
        viewHolder.feed = fp;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvVersionName;
        public ImageView iconView;

        public FeddProperties feed;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            tvVersionName = (TextView) itemLayoutView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvVersionName);
            iconView = (ImageView) itemLayoutView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iconId);

            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = null;
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                            break;

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "You Clicked at " + feed.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ((Selection) getActivity()).onSelection(position);
                    }

                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```